# How to display name with the id but with datas in 2 collections MongoDb?

Tags: mongodb

I just want change a Id by thea name corresponding. But id is in a collection and name in other collection. "$lookup" Mongo doesn't work in my case...

*The first collection "parameter" contains items with the "**category_id**":*

```
{"_id" : ObjectId("56cc8827b9e4ed0fd42a4569"), 
    "data" : {
        "capacity" : NumberInt(60), 
        "categories" : [
            {
                "category_id" : "5964961294ff4a37988e8f9b", 
                "nbMax" : NumberInt(1), 
                "nbRes" : NumberInt(0)
            }, 
            {
                "category_id" : "596495c994ff4a37988e8f99", 
                "nbMax" : NumberInt(1), 
                "nbRes" : NumberInt(0)
            }, 
        ], 
      }, 
    "type" : "launcher", 
    "name" : "launcherp01", 
    "description" : "", 
    "_class" : "parameter"
}
....

{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("56cc8827b9e4ed0fd42a4847"),
    "data" : {
        "capacity" : NumberInt(60), 
        "categories" : [
            {
                "category_id" : "596495c994ff4a37988e8f99", 
                "nbMax" : NumberInt(1), 
                "nbRes" : NumberInt(0)
            }, 
            {
                "category_id" : "8864961294ff4a37988e8f3b", 
                "nbMax" : NumberInt(1), 
                "nbRes" : NumberInt(0)
            }, 
        ], 
      }, 
    "type" : "launcher", 
    "name" : "launcherp01", 
    "description" : "", 
    "_class" : "parameter"
}
.....
```

*The second Collection "reference" contains the description of categories with the **_id** (same as **category_id** in first collection) and the **name**:*

```
{
   "_id" : ObjectId("596495c994ff4a37988e8f99"), 
    "taskType" : "qc", 
    "type" : "category", 
    "name" : "**qcSupportNormal01**", 
    "_class" : "reference", 
}

{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("5964961294ff4a37988e8f9b"),
    "taskType" : "transcode", 
    "type" : "category", 
    "name" : "tsSupportNormal01", 
    "_class" : "reference", 
}
```

I want something like that (item with categories **names** not id):

```
  { 
        "_id" : ObjectId("56cc8827b9e4ed0fd42a4569"), 
        "type" : "launcher", 
        "categories" : [
            "qcSupportNormal01", //--->> name from reference collection
            "tsSupportNormal01", //--->> name from reference collection
    }     

    { 
        "_id" : ObjectId("56cc8827b9e4ed0fd42a4847"), 
        "type" : "launcher", 
        "categories" : [
            "qcSupportNormal01", //--->> name from reference collection
            "qptestNormal01",    //--->> name from reference collection
    ...
```

*My query:*

```
db.parameters.aggregate([
///////////////////////item filter
    {$match: {
      type:{ $in: [ "launcher" ] } ,
    }},  
///////////////////// foreign field      
    {$lookup: {
            from: "references",
            localField: "categories",
            foreignField: "_id",
            as: "references"
    }},
/////////////////// projection 
    {$project:
        {_id:1,type:1,categories:"$data.categories.category_id"
    }},
])
```

but the result is always with id not the name:

```
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("56cc8827b9e4ed0fd42a4569"), 
    "type" : "launcher", 
    "categories" : [
        "5964961294ff4a37988e8f9b", //--->> id not name from reference collection !
        "596495c994ff4a37988e8f99", //--->> id not name from reference collection !
       ...
```

How to have the category name not the id. 
Very simple in Sql (joint with foreign key and reference table) but complex in Mongo query ...

Thanks for your help

je déteste le langage Mongo !

Comment: Please share both collection and with what you want collection at jsoneditor

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of issues with your approach:

1. You are trying to call `$lookup` between an `ObjectId` and a `string` value.
2. For your `categories` field you are mapping it with the `category_id` from the `data.categories` whereas it should have come from `references.name`.
3. The field `category_id` is nested inside of an array and when you are calling the `$lookup` you are matching it with the whole array instead of the `key` field.

So, now the best approach would be to convert the field `category_id` to an `ObjectId` and then call the `$lookup` for the field(*instead of modifying the actual field i have appended a new field named as `cat_id`*).

Here is how i would do it:

```
db.parameter.aggregate([    
{
    $match: {
        type: { $in: ["launcher"] },
    }
},
{ $unwind: "$data.categories" },
{ $addFields: { "data.categories.cat_id": { $convert: { input: "$data.categories.category_id", to: "objectId" } } } },
{
    $lookup: {
        from: "references",
        localField: "data.categories.cat_id",
        foreignField: "_id",
        as: "ref"
    }
},
{
    $project:
        {
            _id: 1, type: 1, categories: "$ref.name"
        }
}
]);
```

Which will give you an output as:

```
{
"_id" : ObjectId("56cc8827b9e4ed0fd42a4569"),
"type" : "launcher",
"categories" : [
    "tsSupportNormal01"
]
},
{
"_id" : ObjectId("56cc8827b9e4ed0fd42a4569"),
"type" : "launcher",
"categories" : [
    "**qcSupportNormal01**"
]
},
{
"_id" : ObjectId("56cc8827b9e4ed0fd42a4847"),
"type" : "launcher",
"categories" : [
    "**qcSupportNormal01**"
]
},
{
"_id" : ObjectId("56cc8827b9e4ed0fd42a4847"),
"type" : "launcher",
"categories" : [ ]
}
```

Comment: Thank you vikscool but i am on Mongo 3.4,  $convert exist since mongo 4.0. I looking for cast string to object in 3.4.

Comment: @caloux i would suggest upgrading the MongoDB to the latest or at least v4.0(*So, you can use more useful features*). If not possible you may have to write a script to perform the output with a flow of something like 1. Create an Array of all the Categories' `name` with their `_id` in a `string` and then another array from `parameter` with `filter=' launcher'` and then do a foreach loop on the `parameter` obj and append the matching values from the categories array.

Comment: @ vikscool thank you for your feedback, i will update to v4.0, better for useful features.